# MSBuild recompile project when only output path change

Tags: compilation, msbuild, target

We have two projects A and B. B referes to A. We created two targets for MSBuild to compile where difference is only in output path (it is separated file, not projects csproj's). Immidiate folder for both project are standard I mean **obj** folder.

We run first target (MSBuild from command line with /t switch) - everything compile ok. We didn't change anything in cs but we changed output path and compile. In that case A is not recompiled but B is fully recompiled. So in output path we had A with the same version but B versions are different.

Do you know why B project is recompiled?

**EDIT**

After some research it looks like MSBuild takes output path as part of cache hash (this file: obj\Debug\CoreCompileInputs.cache).

We call MSBuild like this:

```
msbuild mysolution.sln /p:OutputPath=c:\mydir
```

and csprojs are standard VS2017 csproj.

Comment: Did the output path for project A change as well?

Comment: Yes, for both projects

Comment: Can you post the msbuild code used for building those projects, and specify what kind of projects they are (C++/C#/...)?